# Memory Leaks During Debug Sessions - Possible Threat?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

While programming, I compile and test application maybe hundred of times a day. Moreover, I use to put my computer into sleep mode overnight, so memory does not get cleaned by the fresh system start.

Often, I postpone solving memory leaks for later, say a particular day in a week. My question is, **whether memory leaks that occur during debugging sessions can accumulate and affect the stability of whole system.** Alternatively, is all the memory automatically released by the operating system, after the debugged application exit?

*I develop in C++ under Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 x64.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the operating system cleans up when the process terminates.

Answer (score 3):

If you develop for Windows, the memory of one process is shielded from that of another process.  Inactive processes will have their (non-commited) RAM pages flushed to disk, so that physical memory stays available for active processes.  So stability will not be affected (apart from a lonely bug in the operating system).

Less in control are other resource leaks, e.g. the number of open handles, coming forth of leaked objects holding them.  These may very well cause system instability.

Comment: +1 for good quality answer. Yeah, I had no clue about that, so it was good idea to ask. Thank you. I will wait couple of moments to see if somebody else adds valuable information. I will close this thread afterwards.